# Getting zxing to run in portrait mode

Tags: android, zxing

I'am trying to get a qrcode reader inside my app, without having another app installed, using zxing. But can't make it to show in portrait.

I've read about this in stack overflow and in loads of other websites but the issue persists in my case.

Basically everyone says this is the solution:

https://gist.github.com/border/7577978

But the only thing I get is that the activity is still in landscape but, the rectangle now is smaller ( with the portrait dimensions) and the camera becomes weird because the image is rotated 90 degrees and moves down when I move the phone left and up when moving the phone right.

Some say you need to delete the check:

```
    if    (width > height) {
  Log.i(TAG, "Display reports portrait orientation; assuming this is incorrect");
  int temp = width;
  width = height;
  height = temp;
}
```

In the CameraConfigurationManager.java but that check is not there anymore:

[CameraConfigurationManager.java](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/camera/CameraConfigurationManager.java)

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded? I am using it and this is a perfect free plugin to scan barcode

Comment: @MrNeo I really only want to scan QR codes. Can I do it with that plugin or it is for barcode only? Is there any tutorial of how to set it up?

Comment: hmm, I am using this to scan both QR code and barcode. I will update my project to github, you could try it

Comment: solved the problem with the zxing-android-embedded. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow the instruction in [the link](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) to set up ZXing in your application. If not, you could download ZXing library into your computer and add it in libs folder.
After that, you could use ZXing in your app in Portrait mode or set it in a `layout` by using `CompoundBarcodeView`.

Please refer [my project](https://github.com/kienntk/SNBarcodeScanRes). I am using ZXing for it. Hope this help!

Answer (score 6):

## Try This

Just add this lines to your **manifest** file if you are using this library(**compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'**) for QR code.

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        tools:replace="screenOrientation" />
```

Comment: no no changes for me. but the library is now 3.5.0